# How to print the outputs on excel file to each columns by using perl?

Tags: perl

How to write the output in each rows and each columns?

```
use Win32::OLE;
@a = (1..5);
@b = (20..30);
@c = (30..48);
@array = ("@a","@b","@c");
my $xl = Win32::OLE->new('Excel.Application');
$xl->{EnableEvents} = 0;
$xl->{Visible} = 1;
my $wb = $xl->Workbooks->Add;
my $sht = $wb->Sheets(1);
$sht->{Name} = "Occurance";
foreach $s (@array){
    @each = split(' ',$s);
    $col++;
    foreach (@each){
        $row++;
        $sht->cells($row,$col)->{Value} = "$_";
    }
}
```

In this script gives output, But i expect the array value of "@b" write to the column B, Row 1 to end of array.  Then "@c" write to the column  c, Row 1 to end of array. How can do it?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Always include [`use strict;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) and [`use warnings`](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) in EVERY perl script.  Also, a smaller note is typically it's a good idea to not use `$a` or `$b` for variable names because they are reserved for [`sort`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html)

Comment: @Miller: `@a` is not `$a`.

Comment: @choroba I was referring to the [identifier](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Identifier-parsing), not the type.  One should avoid `%a`, `@a`, and `$a` equally because [`strict`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) won't be able to do its job fully for that identifier.  Just want to give as much of a helping hand to a new programmer as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You're not initializing $row in the column loop.

What you have is:

```
foreach $s (@array){
    $col++;
    foreach (@$s){
        $row++;
        $sht->cells($row,$col)->{Value} = "$_";
    }
}
```

Add 'my $row = 0;'

```
foreach $s (@array){
    $col++;
    my $row = 0;
    foreach (@$s){
        $row++;
        $sht->cells($row,$col)->{Value} = "$_";
    }
}
```

For a little more advanced perl, you can make @array an array of arrays instead of an array of strings:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Win32::OLE;
my @a = (1..5);
my @b = (20..30);
my @c = (30..48);
my @array = (\@a,\@b,\@c);
my $xl = Win32::OLE->new('Excel.Application');
$xl->{EnableEvents} = 0;
$xl->{Visible} = 1;
my $wb = $xl->Workbooks->Add;
my $sht = $wb->Sheets(1);
$sht->{Name} = "Occurance";
my $col = 0;
foreach my $s (@array){
    $col++;
    my $row = 0;
    foreach my $item (@$s){
        $row++;
        $sht->cells($row,$col)->{Value} = $item;
    }
}
```